# C# - DatagridView and ContextMenu

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a datagridview where I show infomation about products. I want to bind a contextmenu when the user selects a cell and then right clicks on that cell. I have another contextmenu and that one is bound to the columns of the datagridview. If a user right clicks on a column the contextmenu shows.

I have tried like this but it does not work. The context menu shows when the user right clicks on a cell, but the contextmenu that is bound to the column header does not work.

```
   private void GridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            productContextMenu.Show(GridView1, e.Location);
        }

    }
```

How do I make it so that when the user right clicks on a datagridview shows up?

Many thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

Thnx for the answers. I solved the problem like this:

```
    private void GridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            hitTestInfo = GridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                productContextMenu.Show(GridView1, e.Location);
            }

        }
    }
```

Both the contextmenus shows. When I click on the column that context menu shows, and when I click on a cell that contextmenu shows.

Comment: Thanks for knowing that you got an answer :)

Comment: Why don't you mark as answer then if you got the solution with his idea

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {
        contextMenu.Show(datagridview, e.Location);
  }

}
```

or

```
 private void dataGridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   // Load context menu on right mouse click
   DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo;
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      hitTestInfo = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
      // If column is first column
      if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 0)
        contextMenuForColumn1.Show(dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    // If column is second column
      if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 1)
        contextMenuForColumn2.Show(dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but it does not work. When I right klick on the datagridview column the context menu shows, but when I right klick on a cell the context menu doese not work.

Comment: For some reason, I am always getting column 0 for _hitTest.ColumnIndex_. Here is my code to add the listener: **dataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick;** and here is my listener definition: **private void dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)**

Answer (score 1):

For the problem with the relative position, you can also use this aproach:

```
DataGridViewColumn dgvC = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewRow dgvR = new DataGridViewRow();
dgvC = dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
dgvR = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Point p = new Point();
p.X = (dgvC.Width * e.ColumnIndex) + e.X;
p.Y = (dgvR.Height * e.RowIndex) + e.Y;
dgv.ContextMenu.Show(dgv, p);
```